# Atoms of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $f : (X, \mathcal F_X) \to (Y, \mathcal F_Y)$ is measurable. Is there a characterisation of the atoms of $\sigma (f)$?

For example, suppose that the singletons $\{y\} \in \mathcal F_Y$ for all $y\in Y$. Is $f^{-1}(y)$ an atom of $\sigma (f)$? Are all atoms of $\sigma(f)$ of the form $f^{-1}(y)$?

Definition: A non-empty set $E \in \Sigma$ is an atom if $F \subsetneq E$ and $F \in \Sigma$ implies $F = \emptyset$.

Comment: In the case that $\mathcal F_Y$ contains all singletons, you have just characterized the atoms. Verifying that is not that hard, you can use the fact that $\sigma(f)=\{f^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal F_Y\}$.

Comment: If $f$ is onto, you can prove that the atoms of $\sigma(f)$ are all the nonempty sets of the form $f^{-1}(B)$, where $B$ is an atom of $\mathcal{F}_Y$. Otherwise, you can force $f$ to be onto by restricting the codomain to $f(X)$, endowed with the $\sigma$-algebra $\{f(X) \cap B : B \in \mathcal{F}_Y\}$.